Show that for all numbers $z\ge 0$, $|z-1|\ge \delta$ implies $|z^2-1|\ge \max\{\delta,\delta^2\}$
How to prove the following result: fix $\delta\ge 0$, for all numbers $z\ge 0$, $|z-1|\ge \delta$ implies $|z^2-1|\ge \max\{\delta,\delta^2\}$.

I did not see why do we need to discuss $0\le \delta \le 1$ and $\delta>1$...
We have
$$
|z^2-1|=|z-1||z+1|\ge \delta |z+1|\ge \delta|z-1|=\delta^2...
$$

You also have to prove that $|z^2-1|\ge \delta$.

You don't need to discuss those cases, but you can solve it that way.
If you've already shown that $|z+1| \geq |z-1|$, then that's really the hardest part to this proof.  To complete the proof, you just need to note the comparatively simple $|z+1| = z+1 \geq 1$.  As a result, $|z+1| \geq \max(|z-1|, 1)$.
The analogous argument would then go
$$|z^2-1| = |z-1||z+1| \geq |z-1|\max(|z-1|,1) \geq \delta \max(\delta, 1) = \max(\delta^2, \delta).$$
